# Run AutoIt script within Selenium test executed from Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, autoit

When running the script manually from within Eclipse, AutoIt works fine and uploads the document, however, when the test build is executed by Jenkins, AutoIt does not work and the script fails with the upload dialog open.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(StoredVariables.getautoIT().get() + "UploadDocument.exe " + StoredVariables.getautoIT().get() + " \"" + fileName + "\"");
```